# Using ToastNotificationManager in .Net5.0

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-5

I was using the following code to show a Windows 10 Toast notifications from a .NetCore 3.1 console application, where I was using objects from the following namespaces: `Windows.UI.Notifications` & `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom`, in .Net5.0 these namespaces seem to be moved to somewhere else.

```
 public void GenerateToast(string appid, string imageFullPath, string h1, string h2, string p1)
        {
            try
            {

                var template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

                var textNodes = template.GetElementsByTagName("text");

                textNodes[0].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h1));
                textNodes[1].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h2));
                textNodes[2].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(p1));

                if (File.Exists(imageFullPath))
                {
                    XmlNodeList toastImageElements = template.GetElementsByTagName("image");
                    ((XmlElement)toastImageElements[0]).SetAttribute("src", imageFullPath);
                }
                IXmlNode toastNode = template.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
                ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

                var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(appid);
                var notification = new ToastNotification(template);

                notifier.Show(notification);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
```

**How to get back these namespaces?**

Comment: WinRT support was [removed in .NET5](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/18875)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance):

This option is only supported in projects that use .NET 5 (or a later release) and target Windows 10, version 1809 or a later OS release. For more background info about this scenario, see this blog post.

1. With your project open in Visual Studio, right-click your project in Solution Explorer and choose Edit Project File. Your project file should look similar to this.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

2. Replace the value of the TargetFramework element with one of the
   following strings:

   `net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0`: Use this value if your app targets
   Windows 10, version 1809.
   `net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0`: Use this value
   if your app targets Windows 10, version 1903.
   `net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0`: Use this value if your app targets
   Windows 10, version 2004.

   For example, the following element is for a project that targets
   Windows 10, version 2004.

```
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

3. Save your changes and close the project file.